# How do I retrieve the contents of a tag?

Tags: jquery, attributes, tags

Say I have the following:

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass"></div>
```

What I would like to do is find this tag via jQuery and get the stuff between <> for this div.  In this case I would like for my output to be as follows:

```
div id="myid" class="myclass"
```

Not looking for innerHTML, just what's in the tag. I know I can use jQuery to test for known attributes, but I'm really looking to be able to get the actual string here. It occurred to me that I could get the innerHTML of a parent tag and then do some parsing, but that seems messy and error prone.  I would much rather be able to do something like the following

```
alert($('#myid').getTagContents())
```

and have it alert the bit above.  Is this possible?  Any idea on how to do it?

FYI, I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate, but the other question does not address my concerns.  I don't want to loop through attributes.  I want the literal string from the tag, so I can parse it myself.

Comment: Why do you need the attributes in that format?

Comment: If the element has childs, do you want them?

Comment: You'd have to build something yourself and just inspect each thing you want and place it within the string. `$('#myid').attr('id')`, etc etc

Comment: You can use `outerHTML` property, actually: it's quite [cross-platform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML) these days. )

Comment: *"Is this possible? Any idea on how to do it?"* Sure, it's possible. However, it's going to take you parsing the element manually, there's no built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should retrieve what you want.

```
alert($('#myId')[0].outerHTML.split('>')[0].substring(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to build something yourself. Made a real quick jQuery extension that returns the result.

http://jsfiddle.net/aY4nG/

```
$.fn.getTagContents = function () {
     var $this = $(this),
         tags  = $this[0].outerHTML,
         endLoc = '';

    endLoc = tags.indexOf('>') - 1;

    return tags.substr(1, endLoc);
};

var tags = $('#test').getTagContents();

console.log(tags);
// logs: div id="test" class="whatever"
```